# How to get Open Extensions properties of All Group Members using Microsoft Graph SDK in a single Get command

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

In Azure Active Directory, While creating a user in Azure AD, I'm adding *Extention* data for each users using the [OpenTypeExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview?tabs=csharp#open-extensions)

Below is the snippet which is being used to add *Extention* data to each user while creating a new user in Azure AD.
Here, I'm adding three *Extension* properties to each users namely (`acsid`, `defaultgroupid` and `useryominame`)

```
var openTypeExtension = new OpenTypeExtension();
                openTypeExtension.ExtensionName = "com.mysite.user.extprofile";
                openTypeExtension.AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                openTypeExtension.AdditionalData.Add("acsid", "8:acs:0e9c3151-234r-4e5b-3245-37ffaa4d79ab_00000017-2erf-75bc-8876-c93a0d00abcd");
                openTypeExtension.AdditionalData.Add("defaultgroupid", "347e12e4-9cf1-437b-f4r5-6dcc7452234d");
                openTypeExtension.AdditionalData.Add("useryominame", "myyominame");

var extensionresult = await _graphClient.Users[user.Id].Extensions["com.mysite.user.extprofile"].Request().GetAsync();
```

Now, once the user is created and respective extensions properties (`acsid`, `defaultgroupid` and `useryominame`) is also added to the user in Azure AD.

But, when I try to fetch **all** the **Group members** using Microsoft Graph SDK, the list of users/members does not returns '*extensions*' properties (`acsid`, `defaultgroupid` and `useryominame`).

Below is the code snippets to get the **Group members**.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = await GetGraphClient()
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);

                var groupMembers = await graphClient.Groups[id].Members
                    .Request()
                    .GetAsync()
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);

                var usersInGroup = groupMembers.OfType<User>().ToList();
```

In the above code snippets variable `usersInGroup`  does not contains extensions properties (`acsid`, `defaultgroupid` and `useryominame`)

So, after getting the `usersInGroup`  list, I had to iterate each user from the list and then get the *Extension* properties.

Below is the code where I'm using for-loop to iterate through each users and then Get the *Extensions* properties for each users.

Note: *Here, I'm using `Parallel.ForEach` instead of simple `foreach` to optimize my response time.*

```
Parallel.ForEach(usersInGroup, user =>
                {
                    var userWithExtensions = graphClient.Users[user.Id].Extensions["com.mysite.user.extprofile"].Request().GetAsync();
                    user.AdditionalData = userWithExtensions?.Result.AdditionalData;
                }
                );
```

**I'm thinking, If Microsoft Graph SDK provide any options where we can get the Extensions directly while getting the Group Members.**

Answer (score 1):

The `extensions` is a navigation property for `user` resource type.

You can use OData cast to get only a list of user membership and include extensions

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/members/microsoft.graph.user?$expand=extensions
```

To write the query above in C# SDK v4

```
// append OData cast microsoft.graph.user to groups/{id}/members url
var url = graphClient.Groups[id].Members.AppendSegmentToRequestUrl("microsoft.graph.user");

// create a new instance of GroupMembersCollectionWithReferencesRequestBuilder
var groupMembersBuilder = new GroupMembersCollectionWithReferencesRequestBuilder(url, graphClient);

// expand extensions and get result
var groupMembers = await groupMembersBuilder
                .Request()
                .Expand("extensions")
                .GetAsync();

foreach (var member in groupMembers)
{
    if (member is User user)
    {
        // user.Extensions
    }
}
```

For SDK v5

```
var response = await graphClient.Groups[id].Members.GraphUser.GetAsync(x =>
    {
        x.QueryParameters.Expand = new[] { "extensions" };
    });
var users = response.Value;
```

Comment: I tried your code in C# SDK v4, while debugging I do see that Extensions are included in ```groupMembers```. However, it seems that ```member ``` is not of type ```User``` and due to this it is not able to serialize the object member into user. And Also this ```if``` condition ```if (member is User user)``` is not coming true throughout the for loop.

Comment: One of my major requirement is to _remove_ the use for-loop. I wanted to retrieve full ```User``` list along with the ```Extensions``` values. So, after retrieving the ```groupMembers``` with Extensions from this code ```var groupMembers = await groupMembersBuilder.Request().Expand("extensions").GetAsync();``` can we directly serialize this to ```User``` object?